# Not able to parse a JSON getting com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object

Tags: java, json

My json

```
1. {"distinctvalue":"-1","classLabel":[{"key":"-1","value":0},{"key":"\u003e4.0","value":3}],"total":3}
2. {"distinctvalue":"1","classLabel":[{"key":"\u003c\u003d4.0","value":1},{"key":"1","value":0}],"total":1}
```

I want to extract "classLabel". So for that I have a POJO class of

```
public class AttrClsJson {
/**
 * @param args
 */
 String key;
 int value;
```

Code

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println("arr.get(i).toString()---------->"+arr.get(i).toString());
     AttrClsJson clsInfo = gson.fromJson(arr.get(i).toString().trim(), AttrClsJson.class);
     int val = clsInfo.getValue();
     System.out.println("val--- "+val);
}
```

For first json I am able to get the key and value from "classLabel"

```
1. arr.get(i).toString()---------->{key=-1, value=0.0}
val--- 0
arr.get(i).toString()---------->{key=>4.0, value=3.0}
val--- 3
2.
arr.get(i).toString()---------->{key=<=4.0, value=1.0}
```

For the above string I am not able to get the value.

And an error is thrown in line `"AttrClsJson clsInfo = gson.fromJson(arr.get(i).toString().trim(), AttrClsJson.class);"`

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 8
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:818)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
```

Am I doing anything wrong?
Please suggest.

EDIT

{key=<=4.0, value=1.0}

When I examined The value is not retrieved when key contains "<=", for all others I am able to get the value.

Comment: How are you getting your `arr` array ? And what is it tho ?

Comment: Looks like a `Map`, which produces a `toString` value which is not JSON at all.

Comment: JSONArray arr = attrInfo.getClassLabel(); from another POJO

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: If I am not using toString it shows cast error

Comment: If this is a JSONArray, doesn't your json objects need to be separated through comma? And what does produces 1. and 2. labels?

Comment: @drgPP : No I just print the array content only.I did nt used gson.toJson() while printing

Comment: Try to use escape characters on key for the "<=" symbol/ANSI representation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're parsing too many times.  You presumably had to parse the JSON Strings to get arr.  You're parsing the content of arr, but it's already been parsed and is no longer a JSON String.

Answer (score 0):

Add backslash before every special character in you string.

Ex. String = "[{\"key\":\"\u003e4.0\",\"value\":3}]";